# Gradient Descent wrt matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, vector-analysis, machine-learning

Suppose $\mathbf{X}$ is a p x n matrix, $\mathbf{Y}$ is q x n, $\mathbf{C}$ is an unknown q x p matrix.  Can you minimize the following with gradient descent to find C?  (multivariate regression)

$|| \mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{C}\mathbf{X}||^2_F$

Wouldn't the gradient wrt $\mathbf{C}$ just be

$\nabla g = -2 (\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{C}\mathbf{X}) \mathbf{X}'$

Comment: The gradient is $-2C^T(Y-CX)$. Just expand $\|Y-C(X+H)\|^2_F$ and take first order terms of $H$.

Comment: @copper.hat it's a gradient with respect to $C$, not $X$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Ahh, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Or explicitly, if $g(C) = \langle Y-CX, Y-CX \rangle$, we have
$g(C+H) -g(C) = -2  \langle Y-CX, HX \rangle+ O(\|H\|^2)$ and since
$\langle Y-CX, HX \rangle = \operatorname{tr}((Y-CX)^T HX) = \operatorname{tr}(X(Y-CX)^T H) = \langle (Y-CX)X^T, H \rangle $.

Hence $\nabla g(C) = -2(Y-CX)X^T$.

Comment: I'm not very much of proof-goer, but can I safely assume that $\nabla_C\lVert XC - Y \rVert_F^2 = -2X^T(XC
 - Y)$?

Comment: I get $-2 X^T (Y-XC)$.

Comment: Man, you're really good at this. Do you know any resources or textbooks that I could teach myself these concepts? My knowledge barely goes beyond derivatives of single-valued multi-variable functions. Every time I try to lay my hands on these kinds of derivatives my brain goes on block! :-(

Comment: @AshkanRanjbar Not really :-(. Just practice, grind & checking. Plus a few tricks with the trace operator.

Answer (score 1):

Your function can be written in the form
$$
g(C) = \operatorname{tr}[(Y - CX)(Y - CX)'] = 
\operatorname{tr}[CXX'C] - 2\operatorname{tr}[CXY'] + [\text{const}]
$$
Following [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities), the gradient (either the transpose of the derivative in the left side column, or equivalently the derivative in the right-most column) will be
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial C} = [(Y - CX)(-X') + (-X)(Y - CX)']' - [2XY']' \\
= -X(Y - CX)' - (Y - CX)X' - 2YX'.
$$

---

For a more abstract approach, note that

$$
g(C+H) = \operatorname{tr}[(Y - [C+H]X)(Y - [C+H]X)']\\
= g(C) - \operatorname{tr}[HX(Y - CX)'] - \operatorname{tr}[(Y - CX)X'] + o(H)\\
= g(C) - 2\operatorname{tr}[HX(Y - CX)'] + o(H).
$$
We therefore find that $dg = -\operatorname{tr}[2X(Y - CX)' dC]$, so that the gradient is equal to 
$$
-[X(Y - CX)']' = -2(Y - CX)X'.
$$
This matches your result.

Comment: @copper.hat yep! Thanks for that

Comment: Great, thank you!!  I missed a - sign, so I've edited the question.  Now you're saying I can use gradient descent to solve for C, correct?  That is start with a $\mathrm{C}$ (with values), and use a loop with a parameter alpha $\mathrm{C}^+ = \mathrm{C} - \alpha \nabla g$ until it converges??

Comment: @Rich that's basically right.  You might find it useful to vary the parameter as you go, though.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks!

Comment: @copper.hat missed your comment the first time, fixed

Answer (score 1):

You do not need gradient descent to solve a linear equation.

Simply use the Moore-Penrose inverse $X^+$ 
$$\eqalign{
CX &= Y \quad\implies\quad C = YX^+ \\
}$$
You can also include contributions from the nullspace (multiplied by an arbitrary matrix $A$)
$$\eqalign{
C = YX^+  + A(I-XX^+) \\
}$$