# Gradient Descent convergence - multivariate regression

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, machine-learning, least-squares, gradient-descent

Follow up to this post: [Does gradient descent converge to a minimum-norm solution in least-squares problems?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451272/does-gradient-descent-converge-to-a-minimum-norm-solution-in-least-squares-probl), but with all matrices

Suppose we are given $p \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{X}$ and $q \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{Y}$. We would like to find $q \times p$ matrix $\mathbf{C}$ such that the following loss function

$$\| \mathbf{Y} - \mathbf{C} \mathbf{X}\|_F^2 $$

is minimized.  How can we prove that gradient descent to estimate $C$ (multivariate regression) converges to a solution?

@Rodrigo de Azevedo provided a nice example responding to the previously mentioned question.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean gradient descent with a fixed step size? Broadly you need to know something about the Lipschitz constant of the gradient. One can always pick a step size rule such as the Armijo step size and then it will always converge (numerics notwithstanding).

Comment: Yes, fixed step size.  I'm trying to prove it will converge

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3558597/339790

Comment: If the question is one of a family of questions on the same problem, please consider linking to the other questions.

Comment: You know the gradient, right? Write the gradient descent update and advance till you get stuck. Then do ask specific questions about the obstacles encountered. Please number such questions.